# Kinds of Expectation-Maximization

Tags: expectation-maximization

I'm starting to dig into the variational inference literature, as I need to solve a learning problem where the latent variables form an hierarchical structure (an hierarchical Gaussian generative model, to be precise). I have defined it using expectation-maximization (EM), and it works well. However, I believe there is room for improvement in both final accuracy, memory, and efficiency, and I believe that these improvements can be achieved by simply using more specific variations of EM. For example, to improve efficiency, I'm thinking about using the incremental EM algorithm, or one of the improved ones (fast-incremental EM).

So, I was wondering whether is there a survey/list of variations of EM online. If not, maybe we could list them into this thread, with links to the paper and a quick description on advantages/limitations? I know some are mentioned on wikipedia, but that list is quite approximative. For example, what is [Dynamical Expectation Maximisation](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18434205/)?